# How to add control for airplay and subtitle in AVplayerViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

[image: Check bottom-right and bottom-left controls]

[image: On subtitle control click, it will open this view]

I'm playing video using AVplayerViewController and I want to add controls for subtitle.

I used `playerController.showsPlaybackControls = true`, but its showing controls except airplay and subtitle. How to add these missing controls?